# How to give focus to the new instance of a form?

Tags: vb.net, instance, multiple-instances, createinstance

I've a program in vb .net with a form named `Form1`. The form has button when I click on the button a dialog window appears. The dialog window has two buttons `OK` and `Cancel`. When the `OK` button is clicked a new instance of `Form1` is created and the new instance is shown. See below code.

```
Private Sub ButtonOK_Click(...) Handles ButtonOK.Click  
Dim frm1 As New Form1  
frm1.Show()  
End Sub
```

The problem is when a new Form1 is created by the above code, the previously created Form1 gets focused and the newly created Form1 looses focus. But I want the newly created (latest) Form1 to get the focus. How do I do it?

Comment: Have you looked at `ShowDialog` to see if that does what you need?

Comment: @AndrewMortimer 'ShowDialog' disables the previously created instances of 'Form1'. I don't want that to happen. I want all instances of 'Form1' enabled and focusable. So no I want 'show' and not 'ShowDialog'.

Comment: A new Form is activated by default. If yours loses focus (is deactivated), your code is doing that.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Something else is going on, the problem along with the code you've provided don't match.  What kind of code do you have in the Constructor, Load() and/or Shown() events of Form1?

Comment: Have you set the [DialogResult Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult?) on `ButtonOK` to a value other than `None` (probabaly DialogResult.OK)?  If so, clicking ButtonOK will set its parent form's `DialogResult` property to this value; as the parent form is a modal dialog, this will close the modal dialog and activate the window active when `ShowDialog` was called (in this case the original Form1).

Answer (score 1):

I have an application that I need to force the user to input information on a new form before proceeding. You can force the new form to show on top and give it focus by doing the following.

```
 Dim frm1 = New Form1()
 frm1.Show()
 frm1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
 frm1.BringToFront()
 frm1.TopMost = True
 frm1.Focus()
```

Comment: *force the user to input information on a new form before proceeding*: then you call `frm1.ShwDialog()`. Here, all that's after `frm1.Show()` is irrelevant in standard conditions: when you create and show a Form, it's brought to front and activated (focused). The OP has *something*, probably, in the `Deactivated` event of the calling Form or *something* that focuses a Control of a default instance of that Form class.